# Are variables in a scope copied to a different memory location when they go beyond the scope?

Tags: rust

In the following code

```
fn main() {
    let a = get_int();
    address_of(&a);
}
fn get_int() -> i32 {
    let a = 1;
    println!("{:p}", &a);
    a
}
fn address_of<A>(a: &A){
    println!("{:p}", a);
}
```

The output is

```
0x7fff51d1ba94
0x7fff51d1bb1c
```

Why is the memory address different when the same value is printed? Does this mean that a variable in a scope will be copied to a different memory location when it goes beyond the scope?

Comment: The values on the call stack have been popped off because the function returned. If it continued to reference the old addresses, it'd be accessing uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Rust passes variables by value. So if you return a variable it gets a different memory address.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [@MSathieu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45892740/155423), the Rust values returned by value are **moved** to another location. If you have memory allocated in the heap and you print the value of the reference, they will remain the same:

```
fn main() {
    let a = get_int();
    address_of(&(*a));
}
fn get_int() -> Box<i32> {
    let a = Box::new(10);
    println!("{:p}", a);
    a
}
fn address_of<A>(a: &A){
    println!("{:p}", a);
}
```

prints:

```
0x7fc9a6c1f008 
0x7fc9a6c1f008
```

The `Box` itself was moved by value here, but the reference inside it remained the same :-)